# Propel object functions missing

Tags: php, propel

So I'm working on this website, created by another developer. It's running on Propel 1.6.9.

While generating the code, the other developer manages to generate functions that are not generated on my laptop. These functions are missing in the BaseTableName.php file. The missing functions are:

- getByName
- getByPosition
- toArray
- setByName
- setByPosition
- fromArray

Furthermore, in the comments at the beginning of the file there is a difference as well. Probably nothing but just in case, the version and generation date/time is missing in the file generated by the other developer:

> This class was autogenerated by Propel 1.6.9 on:
>    Wed Feb 11 21:29:12 2015

I figured I can copy these functions to the file in the parent folder which contains customized functions. But I would first like to know whether I have a problem in my code generation.

Here is the schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<database name="onterechtbetaald">
  <table name="agency_costs" phpName="AgencyCosts">
    <column name="id" type="Integer" required="true" autoIncrement="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="user_id" type="INTEGER"/>
    <column name="name" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="surname" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="email" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="telnr" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="adres1" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="adres2" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="adres3" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="adres4" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="wadres1" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="wadres2" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="wadres3" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="wadres4" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="zelfstandig" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="makelaar" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="madres1" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="madres2" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="madres3" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="madres4" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="datumingang" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="datumtekenen" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="bedrag" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="bankrek" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="banknaam" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="message" type="LongVarchar"/>
    <column name="message2" type="LongVarchar"/>
    <column name="message3" type="LongVarchar"/>
    <column name="machtiging" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="percentage" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="machtiging_ontvangen" type="Date"/>
    <column name="aanmaning_verzonden" type="Date"/>
    <column name="dagvaarding_verzonden" type="Date"/>
    <column name="factuur_nummer" type="Integer" />
    <column name="factuur_verzonden" type="Date"/>
    <column name="factuur_bedrag" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="zaak_afgesloten" type="Date"/>
    <column name="schikking_bedrag" type="Decimal" size="14" scale="4"/>
    <column name="notice" type="LongVarchar"/>
    <column name="is_special" type="BOOLEAN"/>
    <unique name="IX_UQ_agency_costs_id">
      <unique-column name="id"/>
    </unique>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="users">
      <reference foreign="id" local="user_id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <behavior name="timestampable"/>
  </table>
  <table name="file_meta" phpName="FileMeta">
    <column name="id" type="Integer" required="true" autoIncrement="true" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="case_id" type="Integer"/>
    <column name="title" type="Varchar" size="70"/>
    <column name="description" type="LongVarchar"/>
    <column name="path" type="LongVarchar"/>
    <column name="user_id" type="INTEGER"/>
    <unique name="IX_UQ_file_meta_id">
      <unique-column name="id"/>
    </unique>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="agency_costs">
      <reference foreign="id" local="case_id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="users">
      <reference foreign="id" local="user_id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <behavior name="timestampable"/>
  </table>
  <table name="users" phpName="User" idMethod="native">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" autoIncrement="true" primaryKey="true" phpName="Id"/>
    <column name="username" type="VARCHAR" size="45" phpName="Username"/>
    <validator column="username">
      <rule name="required" message="Username is verplicht veld"/>
    </validator>
    <column name="email" type="VARCHAR" size="45" phpName="Email"/>
    <column name="password" type="VARCHAR" size="45" phpName="Password"/>
    <column name="rank" type="INTEGER" phpName="Rank"/>
    <column name="last_login" type="TIMESTAMP" phpName="LastLogin"/>
    <column name="phone" type="VARCHAR" size="45" phpName="Phone"/>
    <behavior name="timestampable"/>
    <behavior name="timestampable"/>
  </table>
</database>
```

Here is the build.properties:

```
propel.mysql.tableType = InnoDB
propel.database = mysql
propel.project = onterechtbetaald
propel.database.url = mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=xxx
propel.database.user = xxx
```

Comment: What does your schema.xml look like, if you don't mind.  Also, which classes are you using for your queries?

I'm not sure if `getByXXX` and `setByZZZ` are there, or did you means `filterByXX` and `findByZZZ`

Comment: I appreciate your reply Qiniso, but for one I don't like to give away my database structure. Secondly, I don't see how this will shed any light on the problem I'm facing. If I'm wrong, please explain why it would be useful so I can reconsider. The classes I'm using are not included in this missing functions. I mostly use filterBy, orderBy, joinWith and findPk. From then functions missing in the classes generated on my laptop, I am really missing the functionality of toArray and fromArray. I'd like to know why these are not created on my laptop but are created on the laptop of the previous dev.

Comment: Your schema may not be relevant, but please provide it anyway - it is the first thing you should be providing with a Propel question. I can't imagine that a database structure has much in the way of intellectual property value, in any case, as 99% of them can be trivially recreated. Thus, this question is probably not answerable in its current form.

Comment: A guess: maybe a missing `name` property from the `<table>` or `<column>` elements?

Comment: Both generated classes use the same schema.xml but I've added it to the question.

Comment: Your schema looks OK to me. The last table has the `timestampable` behaviour twice, which is not correct, so I would remove that. There are a few redundant `phpName` attributes (I only use these if they would actually change the camelcased default name) but I don't expect they would hurt. Have you tried regenerating the base classes? What is the output when you do so?

Comment: I wonder, what does your `build.properties` file look like? I wonder if you have something non-standard in there. Also, how is Propel installed for you? A reinstall via Composer might be worthwhile.

Comment: I've installed Propel via composer and tried several reinstalls to try and solve this problem. This problem occurs when I'm generating the base classes. When the previous developer generates them he creates the functions that for some reason are not generated on my laptop. He is using the exact same files as I do, so the schema.xml and build.properties do not seem relevant for that reason. In the build.properties there is nothing special. These are added to the question as well.

Comment: (I didn't see your reply, you need to respond using @halfer otherwise I won't receive an inbox notification).

Comment: Hmm, this is a very odd problem. If you want, assemble your files on a public GitHub repo (schema, build properties, composer.json, whatever else) and I'll try it on my side if you like. What OS are you and your colleague on? Also, check your `php -m` on both of your machines. I wonder if maybe you are missing `libxml` or something like that? Now, I would hope Propel would complain if it needs something it doesn't have but...

Comment: Also, have you tried doing a diff between the `om` generation output on your machines? Maybe there is an error you have missed.